# Using attributes in Chef Solo JSON

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Is it possible to specify attribute values in Chef Solo's JSON? I have a solo.json with a run list and I would like to specify the attributes there. The Chef documentation seems to indicate it should be possible for me to do something like:

```
{
    "hostname": {
        "test": "value2"
    },
    "default_attributes": {
        "hostname": {
            "test": "value3"
        }
    },
    "override_attributes": {
        "hostname": {
            "test": "value4"
        }
    },
    "default": {
        "hostname": {
            "test": "value5"
        }
    },
    "run_list": [
        "recipe[hostname::default]"
    ]
}
```

However, whenever I try to access the value in my recipe:

```
p node['hostname']['test']
```

I just get the value defined in attributes/default.rb, and if I do not define it there, I get a nil value back.

Is there a way to reference these values?

Comment: An easier way (to me at least) is to create an "overrides" cookbook that just has an attributes file with `node.override` values and then run `chef-solo -c ~/.chef/solo.rb -j ~/.chef/solo.json -o my_overrides_cookbook,recipe[recipe_to_run]` to guarantee it overrides your defaults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only level of attributes you can store in the node data is `normal`, everything else is reset at the start of the converge and rebuilt from roles, environments, and cookbooks. You want something like looks like this:

```
{
  "normal": {
    "hostname": {
      "test": "something"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[hostname::default]"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow up:

Not setting the attribute precedence level inside the JSON file with Chef Solo works.  The JSON should look similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "my_json_file",
  "description": "JSON run-list and attributes.",
  "my_cookbook": {
    "git_branch": "staging"
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe1]",
    "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe2]",
  ]
}
```

Not including the `"normal": {...}` or `"default_attributes": {...}`, etc, will pass attributes for chef-solo to use.

Comment: Thanks for tip . For chef-solo , after removing "default_attributes": {...} from role file , chef solo honored all attributes , which were part of that role file .

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the above example for setting attributes in a JSON file for chef-solo, and the `"normal": {...}` block was completely ignored.  The run list was read, but attributes never seem to work.

My command is:

```
chef-solo -c /path/to/config_file.rb -j /path/to/file.json
```

My JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "my_json_file",
  "description": "JSON run-list and attributes.",
  "normal": {
    "my_cookbook": {
      "git_branch": "staging"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe1]",
    "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe2]",
  ]
}
```

During the converges, Chef went straight back to the default values inside of `attributes/default.rb`.  Are the JSON values being entered correctly?  So far, my only workaround has been to create a new recipe for each `"git_branch":` attribute I want tested with chef-solo, and adding that updated run-list to a different JSON file.  Essentially, copying an entire recipe to change a single `node.normal['my_cookbook']['git_branch']` value.  Needless to say, this shouldn't be a solution.

Using Chef 14.0.202

Comment: This is not an answer, rather another (may be follow-up) problem :)