# How to pass an attribute from a packer build to a chef coobook?

Tags: chef-infra, packer

I am trying to pre-set a chef-attribute from a packer build but I can't seem to get it work:

```
    "provisioners": [
    {
      "chef_environment": "test_cookbook",

      "environments_path": "environments",
      "execute_command": "{{if .Sudo}}sudo {{end}}chef-solo --no-color --legacy-mode -c {{.ConfigPath}} -j {{.JsonPath}}",
      "json": {
          "test_cookbook": {
            "my_attr": "test"
          }
      },
      "run_list": [
        "test_cookbook"
      ],
      "type": "chef-solo",
    }
  ]
```

It is always getting passed as a nil value

```
output="#{Chef::Log.info(node['my_attr'])}"
log output
file "/tmp/#{node['my_attr']}" do
  content output
end
```

I already referred this [Using attributes in Chef Solo JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010272/using-attributes-in-chef-solo-json) already.

Comment: It appears that the `my_attr` key is nested inside the `test_cookbook` key within the mapping. Have you tried accessing the `test_cookbook` key instead?

Comment: that's the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `json` key for the Chef provisioner for Packer, the attributes passed to Chef will be key-value pairs starting with the key nested inside the `json` key. Therefore, you can access your attributes from within the `test_cookbook` key like:

```
output="#{Chef::Log.info(node['test_cookbook']['my_attr'])}"
log output
file "/tmp/#{node['test_cookbook']['my_attr']}" do
  content output
end
```

and this should assign the String `test` to the local variable `output` and place it as content within your temporary file. This is due to mapping you set up within the `json` key as:

```
"test_cookbook": {
  "my_attr": "test"
}
```